# Synchronization on an object, then on that object's field

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, synchronized

There are multiple threads accessing a single object. To avoid memory consistency errors I have used synchronized methods for that object.
Does it mean that when I synchronize on that object, only the object's fields are synchronized (and not the object's field's fields)?
For example:

```
public class Class1 {

    private Object value1;

    public Object getValue1() {
        return this.value1;
    }

    public void setValue1(Object value1) {
        this.value1 = value1;
    }

}
```

Which code is right (`Class2` or `Class3`) and why?

```
public class Class2 {

    private final Class1 object1 = new Class1();

    private Object value2;

    public synchronized void setValues(Object value1, Object value2) {
        object1.setValue1(value1);
        this.value2 = value2;
    }

    public synchronized Object[] getValues() {
        return new Object[] { object1.getValue1(), this.value2};
    }

}

public class Class3 {

    private final Class1 object1 = new Class1();

    private Object value2;

    public synchronized void setValues(Object value1, Object value2) {
        synchronized (object1) {
            object1.setValue1(value1);
        }
        this.value2 = value2;
    }

    public synchronized Object[] getValues() {
        Object value1;
        synchronized (object1) {
            value1 = object1.getValue1();
        }
        return new Object[] { value1, this.value2};
    }

}
```

More specific:

```
Class2 obj = new Class2();

// thread 1
obj.setValues(..., ...);

// thread 2
Object[] values = obj.getValues();
```

Since both `setValues` and `getValues` are synchronized there will be happens-before relationship between `this.value2 = value2;` and `return new Object[] {..., this.value2};` in `Class2`.
But what about `object1`? There is no guarantees that `this.value1 = value1;` happens before `return this.value1;` in `Class1`. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

They're both right, but only because of the specifics of how you're using them (nothing can use `object1` or `value2` other than methods of the instances you're creating, because `object1` or `value2` and private to the instances). The answer to your main question:

> Does it mean that when I synchronize on that object, only the object's fields are synchronized (and not the object's field's fields)?

..is **yes**, only access to that object's fields, not its fields' fields, is synchronized.

Here's an example that could actually demonstrate an issue:

```
class Foo {
    Class1 c1;

    Foo(Class1 c) {
        this.c1 = c;
    }

    synchronized Object getValue1() {
        return c1.getValue1();
    }

    synchronized void setValue1(Object newValue) {
        c1.setValue1(newValue);
    }
}
```

With that, it's possible two instances of `Foo` are sharing the **same** instance of `Class1`:

```
Class1 c1 = new Class1();
Foo f1 = new Foo(c1);
Foo f2 = new Foo(c2);
```

...and since the synchronization only synchronizes access to the `Foo` instance, you could have unsynchronized access to the `Class1` instance that they're both using.

Comment: So there will be no memory consistency errors when accessing `object1`'s `value1` in `Class2`? Why? `object1` and `value2` are both reference fields, and only the values of that fields (i.e. objects' addresses in memory) are synchronized. It's fine for `value2` because we don't access it's own state. But what about `object1`'s `value1`? Is it possible to get "old" value instead of new one? And why?

Comment: @Victor: You don't synchronize fields; you synchronize *threads*. Again: Your examples have a **private** `Class` instance, and the only access to that instance is through synchronized methods that synchronize on the instance that contains it. So only one thread can be using those methods at any given time, and you don't have to do further synchronization. But that's only because your classes have a private instance that no one else has access to. Don't think of synchronizing fields, think of the *threads* using those fields.